# Can't create a new Ruby project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have just started learning Ruby on Rails and I'm stuck in the beginning!
I have installed the package from http://www.railsinstaller.org/ and followed the installation steps. Yet when I type: rails new rubyProject 
I get the following:

```
Gem::InstallError: ffi requires Ruby version <2.5, >= 2.0.
An error occurred while installing ffi <1.9.18>, and bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install ffi -v '1.9.18''succeeded before bundling.
```

I've read a number of articles but non of them worked for me. Can you help me?

Comment: On which ruby version are you?

Comment: on the CMD it shows: Ruby 1.9.3p551

Comment: So the error clearly says that you need a higher ruby version, on which OS are you installing this, Windows or OS X?

Comment: windows 7 32 bits

Comment: So you have option to download the ruby installer for a upgraded version, please try that (a point to note that Rails is not well supported in Windows system according to my experience so you might face many issues while development)

Comment: I downloaded it and installed it but the rails installer keeps displaying the old version ... actually rails is installed as a full package with Ruby inside it so how can I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RailsInstaller does contain a few known bugs.
Lets take a step back and start from scratch.

- Uninstall all traces of Ruby and RailsInstaller on your system.
- Ensure the RailsInstaller setup file says `3.3.0`
- Install RailsInstaller using the default options
- Open the patched version of your `cmd.exe` *(you'll find a new shortcut in your Start Menu)* and configure Git and DevKit tools for your system. Here on always work using this `cmd.exe`. It will start in `C:/Sites` and will automatically show you your Git n Ruby versions.
- Check installed Ruby version. (Should report v2.3.3 as per the website)
- **Then update all installed gems:** (Important)

  1. `gem update --system --no-ri --no-rdoc` to update your Rubygems version
  2. `gem update --no-document`
- Check Rails version. *(`rails -v`)* Should be `5.1.2`